Calculating a measure on all rows based on a subset of the data
I have a dataset containing data like following:



Customer
invoice number
invoice date
payment date
payment_days
open_flag




Customer 1
invoice 1
1/1/24
10/1/24
9
no


Customer 1
invoice 2
1/1/24
20/1/24
19
no


Customer 1
invoice 3
5/1/24
10/1/24
5
no


Customer 2
invoice 4
11/1/24
13/1/24
2
no


Customer 2
invoice 5
11/1/24
13/1/24
2
no


Customer 3
invoice 6
12/1/24
18/1/24
6
no


Customer 1
invoice 7
1/2/24

NA
yes


Customer 2
invoice 8
3/2/24

NA
yes


Customer 3
invoice 9
4/2/24

NA
yes



and I would like to calculate the following columns - which shouldn't be affected by any filter selections!
... | **calculated customer avg** | **expected payment date** |
... | ----------------------- | ------------------------- |      
... | (9 + 19 + 5) / 3 = 11   |          12/1/24          |
... | (9 + 19 + 5) / 3 = 11   |          12/1/24          |
... | (9 + 19 + 5) / 3 = 11   |          16/1/24          |
... |    (2 + 2) / 2 = 2      |          13/1/24          |
... |    (2 + 2) / 2 = 2      |          13/1/24          |
... |      (6) / 1 = 6        |          18/1/24          |
... | (9 + 19 + 5) / 3 = 11   |          12/2/24          |
... |    (2 + 2) / 2 = 2      |          5/2/24           |
... |      (6) / 1 = 6        |          10/2/24          |

My problem is that I can only calculate the avg. days on the closed invoices, but I can't use these calculations on the open invoices.
I can only work in the sheets (Do not have access to the data load editor).
I would like to use this look at the expected payment dates for open invoices, meaning that the calculation should still return a value if I filter out all closed invoices.
I am only able to calculate the avg (where I have removed outliers).
But these are only returned on closed rows...
= Avg(
        IF(
            [invoice date] <> [payment date] and SQRT(POW([invoice date] - [payment date],2)) <= 200, 
        [invoice date] - [payment date], 
        null())) 

Thank You

If I get your question right, this function should do what you want:
Date(invoice_date + Aggr({1} NoDistinct Avg(payment_date-invoice_date), Customer), 'D/M/YY')

It will return the expected_payment_date, even when you filter out the closed invoices, like:

The Aggr() aggregates the payment_days independently from the table object and the set identifier {1} ignores all selections.
Data load statement:
Data:
Load Customer,
     [Invoice Number],
     Date#([Invoice Date], 'D/M/YY') as invoice_date,
     Date#([Payment Date], 'D/M/YY') as payment_date,
     payment_days,
     open_flag     
Inline [
Customer,   Invoice Number, Invoice Date,   Payment Date,   payment_days,   open_flag
Customer 1, invoice 1,  1/1/24,     10/1/24,    9,  no
Customer 1, invoice 2,  1/1/24,     20/1/24,    19, no
Customer 1, invoice 3,  5/1/24,     10/1/24,    5,  no
Customer 2, invoice 4,  11/1/24,    13/1/24,    2,  no
Customer 2, invoice 5,  11/1/24,    13/1/24,    2,  no
Customer 3, invoice 6,  12/1/24,    18/1/24,    6,  no
Customer 1, invoice 7,  1/2/24,     ,            ,  yes
Customer 2, invoice 8,  3/2/24,     ,            ,  yes
Customer 3, invoice 9,  4/2/24,     ,            ,  yes
];


I've been coming back to this issue for weeks now, trying to solve it, but this solution seems to work!
I somehow forgot that in my dataset the open invoices, for some reason, also contains a date value of 31/12/9999.
But I fixed this by adding an if statement instead of the payment_date in your function:
Date(invoice_date + Aggr({1} NoDistinct Avg(IF([open_flag]='yes', null(), [Payment Date])-invoice_date), Customer), 'D/M/YY')
which seems to work, but I don't know if it's the best solution.
Again thank you :)

Cool, glad to help. Btw: If the answer was indeed helpful you could upvote. It helps other people with similar problems on their search and gives me a nice score :-)

For sure - I just needed 15 reputation.
Quick question, and i know this wasnt a part of the original question, so feel free to answer.
but what if i had some invoices which i wouldnt want as a part of my avg. calculation? - but i would still like to be able to add the avg to the invoice date - how would i add this?
Let's says for example that i have an "invoice_type" column, and i only wanted type 1 invoice as part of the avg calculation - but i would still want the avg to be added on type 2 invoices.

That should not be a problem. I would add the set modifier: Aggr({1<invoice_type={1}>} NoDistinct Avg(payment_date-invoice_date), Customer). The only problem here would be if a customer only had invoices of type 1. His expected_payment_days could not be calculated.
